# Function in rake_nltk package returning none keywords

Tags: python, nlp

The following code is returning None keywords:-

```
from rake_nltk import Rake

r=Rake()
testscenario='''This document is very important as it has a lot of business objectives mentioned in it.'''
defect='''Current day per security file is going to Bloomberg and we are getting data back from Bloomberg but it is not loading into the MarkIt tables.  Last date on MarkIt tables for data loaded was June 29, 2016.BBG Run date for what is going into per security matcher is June 29th.See attached for screen shots.'''
print(r.extract_keywords_from_text(testscenario))
```

The output that I am getting is None.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used. It worked for me.

```
from rake_nltk import Rake
r=Rake()
testscenario='This document is very important as it has a lot of business objectives mentioned in it.'
r.extract_keywords_from_text(testscenario)
print(r.get_ranked_phrases())
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/rake-nltk/

Answer (score -1):

Refer to README of the package. It clearly describes what you need to get ranked phrases

```
r.extract_keywords_from_text(testscenario)
```

extracts the keywords from the given text. Use

```
r.get_ranked_phrases()
r.get_ranked_phrases_with_scores()
```

to get the ranked scores and their weights.

Readme link : https://github.com/csurfer/rake-nltk/blob/master/README.md

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the documentation that the methods `extract_keywords_from_text()` and `extract_keywords_from_sentences()` do not return anything. One might reasonably expect `extract_keywords_from_text()` to return a list of keywords. As you say, to retrieve results you need to use the `get_` methods.

Comment: Sorry if the method names weren't descriptive enough. I have made sure documentation is clear enough for the methods so hopefully, it should fill the void.